# How to update all repositories that are made from a template? ... when I update the template

Tags: github

So, I have a project I'm working on. Basically a CMS for property managers to market their properties. I use WHM/cPanel for each project, and I use Github to clone a templated file for each new project. I then add it through Git Version Control in cPanel to deploy new projects. The only thing is, I need to be able to update all of the sites at once, when I update the main template for each site. Is there an easy way to do this? Am I missing something?

What I've been doing is manually updating each site one by one. But, there has to be an easier way.